# How to create a Page where the customer can create their own custom product with WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Well, title's pretty self explanatory. I'm making an E-Shop for selling mugs, and custom made mugs as well, and I need help to create a product page, where the customer can create their own custom mug, using the designs the page is gonna have on display, as well as colors for the handle and/or inside of the mug. This is for my internship by the way.

Comment: You are using any kind of plugin like WooCommerce? You might need Vendor frontend plugin to work with those eCommerce plugins to serve your purpose.

Comment: what plugin do you recommend for that? I've been looking at said plugins for the past few hours and I am not able to find any plugin that can help me with that. The ones that I did find, are mostly for contact forms, and they're for prenium users as well

Comment: Well, for custom frontend you probably have to use premium plugins. I have so far used WCMP with their premium AFM (Advanced Frontend Manager). They are not the number one though. The client I worked for did have some issues with the top ranking plugin as he said. But not sure if the problem still persists, because what I know is, they are very professional in solving such issue rapidly.